# Как запустить через exec() в PHP утилиту mysqldump в Denwer'е?

Tags: php, mysql, denwer, exec, dump

Хочу использовать из PHP-скрипта функционал mysqldump-утилиты: **\usr\local\mysql-5.5\bin\mysqld.exe**, запуская её с нужными мне параметрами через **exec()**

**Вопросы:**

- как добраться на Windows-машине под Denwer'ом до этой утилиты
  \usr\local\mysql-
  5.5\bin\mysqld.exe через команду в php-функции exec()
- и как указывать путь mysqldump-утилите для сохранения файла, чтобы к
  примеру файл сохранялись рядом с моим php-скриптом из которого я всё
  это делаю

Comment: Добейтесь правильной работы утилиты через cmd.exe, когда получите удовлетворительный результат, используйте строку запуска в php скрипте с подстановкой необходимых параметров.

Comment: В чем может быть проблема если из cmd.exe mssqldump работает, а из exec() нет. При этом другие команды из exec() выполняются, например ipconfig возвращает сообщение.